# HTML5 CSS3 <a> element not centering inside of <div> element

Tags: html, css, alignment

```
#buttoncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 23%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
}

.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    font-family: DancingScript-Regular;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.0);
    padding: 15px 15px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #000000, 0 0 5px 5px #888 inset;
    left: 15%;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.buttonText {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
    width:  70px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


#b11 {
    top: 30px;
}

#b22 {
    top: 170px;
}

#b33 {
    top: 305px;
}



        <div id="buttoncontainer">
            <div class="buttons" id="b11">
                <a href="#b11" id= "b1" class="buttonText">Upload</a>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons" id="b22">
                <a href="#b22" id="b2" class="buttonText">Refresh</a>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons" id="b33">
                <a href="#b33" id="b3" class="buttonText">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to make the  element fill up its parent  container. But for some reason it doesn't align itself- as a whole block element inside/center of it's  container, but instead pushes itself downwards and to the right. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that I need the padding to center the text vertically in the bubble. I also tried padding-top: 25px; an still no success on centering the a block element.

EDIT2: I added text-align: center which centers the text correctly in the a element, but again the a element is not centering inside the div.

Comment: Maybe its the padding on the `<a>`.

Comment: If you are referring to `a.buttonText` not being in the center of it's parent, remove padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvpUW/)

Do this in your CSS -

```
.buttons { text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    font-family: DancingScript-Regular;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.0);
    padding: 15px 15px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #000000, 0 0 5px 5px #888 inset;
    left: 15%;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.buttonText { /*    
    width:  70px;
    height: 70px;*/
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 18px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding from class `.buttonText`
Add `line-height: 70px;`, `text-align: center;` to center the links.

```
.buttonText {
    display: block;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; /*Change padding to 0*/
    width:  70px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtW5b/2/)

Comment: I need the padding to center the text vertically in the bubble. I forgot to mention also that I tried padding-top: 25px; an still no success on centering the element.

Comment: @dhee Updated the answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This centers your text vertically and horizontally in the center of the button.

```
.buttonText {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Hope this helps!

(EDIT: Adjust your line height to the height of the button. `vertical-align:middle;` will center it vertically)

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove this in your CSS:

```
.buttonText {padding: 25px;}
```

Make it as:

```
.buttonText {padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions....I finally got it to work with:

```
.buttonText {
    margin-left: -23px;
    margin-top: -23px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 28px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Not sure why this one gave me such a hard time...I usually don't have issues when doing buttons like these.